# Where are sent emails stored on unix?

Tags: smtp

We have smtp installed on the Unix box.
I am looking for the sent emails being sent everyday but not sure which location to look for on unix.

Comment: Are you looking for the source/cause of emails being sent to you everyday? Or an overview of the emails sent from/via the system every day? Or the content of the emails sent from/via the system every day?

Comment: AFAIK e-mails that you sent to someone are not stored when using the basic tools and certainly not using SMTP. You should use IMAP for that.

Comment: Which SMTP server are you using? Which System? (Unix is pretty generic ...)

Answer (score 1):

SMTP servers do not store sent emails: they just deliver them to the specified address.

The server usually stores in a log file information about the sent email (from, to, subject, ...) but not the content.

Answer (score 1):

[SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) is just a protocol to ask a remote server to deliver some mail. You cannot install SMTP on a server, you can only install commands that speak that protocol. Especially there are SMTP clients (that want to send mail) and SMTP servers (that are able to receive mails). You are probably thinking of some [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent).

If you want to have a local copy of your mail you should ask you local mail client to not only send the mail via SMTP, but also to store a local copy of that mail.

The SMTP server usually does not save any mails either. It just forwards mails to the correct destination. At the end there is some [MDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent), which is responsible for storing that mail according to it's configuration.

Therefore I'm not really sure what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve.